# Can't access fixed nav bar when I scroll to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm dealing with a weird issue I've never seen before. I have a fixed navbar on my page with some links on them. Normally, I can click these links and I can access the navbar with the inspector in my Chrome dev tools. 
But something happens when I scroll all the way to the bottom of the page. All of a sudden my navbar stops responding, and I can't even select it with my inspector. I can still see it but behaves as if it doesn't even exist.
I don't even know what kind of code to provide for you guys, because I'm completely dumbfounded by what could be the underlying issue.

Pictures:

Here, it's working. I'm somewhere in the middle of my page, and I can access the navbar just fine. 
[image: works fine here]

Here, my scrollbar is at the very bottom, and now I can't access the navbar. I can only get the entire section. 
[image: doesn't work here]

Here's my code. Sorry if I'm code dumping, I'm just not sure what to show.

```
<div id="main-page">
      <nav>
        <div id="about-top">About</div>
        <div id="projects-top">Projects</div>
        <div id="contact-top">Contact</div>
      </nav>

        <section class="header" id="contact">
            <header role="banner">

              <div class="name">
                <h1>Farah Gustafson</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="occupation">
                <h2>Full stack developer</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="contact">
                <div class="phone">
                  <p class="contact-title">phone</p>
                  <p class="contact-info">(301) ******</p>
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                  <p class="contact-title">email</p>
                  <p class="contact-info">f------</p>
                </div>
                <div class="location">
                  <p class="contact-title">location:</p>
                  <p class="contact-info">Washington</p>
                </div>
                <div class="find-me">
                  <p class="contact-title">find me</p>
                  <a class="contact-info" href="https://github.com/Farahgus10">GitHub</a>
                  <a class="contact-info" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/farah-gustafson/">Linkedin</a>
                </div>
              </div>

            </header>
        </section>

        <section class="about-me">
          <div class="about" id="about">
            <div class="about-box">
              <h1>About</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="bio-box">
              <h3>Bio</h3>
              <p class="bio-text">I'm a full-stack developer who values collaborative work, open minds, and a desire to keep learning above all else.</p>
              <p class="bio-text">Besides coding, a typical week consists of exploring the great outdoors with my dog, learning new cooking skills, or curled up with a good book. </p>
              <p class="bio-text">If you're interested in working with me, or just want to say hello, feel free to contact me through phone, email, or Linkedin.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="skills-box">
              <h3>Skills</h3>
              <p class="skills-text">JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3</p>
              <p class="skills-text">React, jQuery</p>
              <p class="skills-text">Node, Express, PostgreSQL</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="projects-section">
          <div class="projects" id="projects">
            <div class="project-main"><h1>Projects</h1></div>

            <a class="project-link" href="https://farah-sustainachoice-app.now.sh">
              <div class="project-picture"></div>
            </a>

            <div class="project-title">SustainAChoice</div>
            <div class="project-description">An app that allows users in the Washington, D.C. area to find sustainably-sourced food in their area.</br>
              <p class="tech-stack">Technical stack: React, Node, PostgreSQL, Express, CSS</p>

              <a href="">Client-side repo</a></br>
              <a href="">Server-side repo</a></br>
            </div>

          </div>
        </section>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 * { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  }

nav>div {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav div:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.projects-section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.project-main{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: fit-content;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.project-picture{
    top: 60px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-image: url('./Images/NavbarHeader.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.project-title{
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 20px;
    /* font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif; */
}

.project-description{
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.tech-stack{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: grey;
}
.project-description a {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}
.project-description a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.project-link a:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

- Link to [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3521soLh/)

What gives??

Comment: Could you include your CSS?

Comment: @Ruud yep I just added it

Answer (score 0):

Your relative positioned `projects-section` section gets in the way of your nav bar. The relative positioning doesn't seem necessary? Alternatively, you can add a z-index to your nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

Set z-index on navbar to high-value something like 999, that should fix it.

Footer section is overlapping navbar.